# Showing content in select box base on previous select box

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, html

hello developer community.I need your help.i am building a project on attendance management.In this project,i got stucked on one feature.
what i want is to display the departments based on the block input without going to next page.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="block" class="control-label col-sm-2">Select block:</label>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
          <select class="form-control" name="block" id="block">
             <option selected="selected" value="">Select Block:</option>
                <?php 
                      $q="select * from blocks ORDER BY block_name";
                      $res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                         echo "<option value='$row[block_id]'class='form-control'>".$row['block_name']."</option>";
                      }
                ?>
              </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="department" class="control-label col-sm-2">Select department:</label>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
          <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Select Department:</option> 

                      <?php 
                          $q="select * from departments ORDER BY department_name";
                          $res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                               echo "<option  value='$row[department_id]'class='form-control'>".$row['department_name']."</option>";
                          }
                     ?>
          </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: You can use Ajax OR add `block` as a `class` to each and every department. Now, on `onchange` event of first dropdown, hide all elements that don't have this block as a class and show only those departments which have this block as it's class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PHP file, e.g. `dep-getter.php`

```
<?php
// Include your connection config
include 'db-config.php';

// getting block value
$block = $_GET['block'];

$where = !empty($_GET['block']) ? "block='$block'" : '1=1';
$q="select * from departments ORDER BY department_name WHERE $where";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<option  value='$row[department_id]'class='form-control'>".$row['department_name']."</option>";
}
?>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block-select').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/dep-getter.php?block='+val,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.select-department').html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Something went wrong!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I use the before code for simple understanding. For detail explaination, you can read Ajax documentation.

**Note:**
You need adding class to Department select option with name `select-department` as a target to put ajax result.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is using Ajax.
But if you don't know about Ajax yet, the idea is to reload the current page with appending query string with `Block` value, and then show the `Department` base on block value.

So, for getting block value and reloading you can use jQuery for simple way.
The code come like this.

The Block select option (adding class for selector):

```
<select class="block-select">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.block-select').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var curUrl = window.location.href;
    // Append the value to current URL & reload
    var targetUrl = curUrl + '?block=' + val;
    window.location.href = targetUrl;
  });
});
```

And then change your Department select option to like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="department" id="department">
    <?php 
    $where = !empty($_GET['block']) ? "block='$_GET[block]'" : '1=1';
    $q="select * from departments ORDER BY department_name WHERE $where";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        echo "<option  value='$row[department_id]'class='form-control'>".$row['department_name']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

The above code will checking for block value from URL, if the block not empty then we will get department data by block value, otherwise get all.

Comment: thanks for your answer.Can you please tell me about ajax and code of ajax to do my task.

Comment: To use Ajax, you need another PHP file as ajax target. Check my answer below (wait a minute...).

Comment: when i am using your jquery code,it works well. Only problem is when on first time when we accidently select an incorrect option and after reloding we correct our block,it relodes again and after reloding again, it show departments according to previous selected block.

Comment: I think the problem is at the Block selected option, you must have a condition to set an option to be selected.

Comment: Something like this: `$selected = $row['block_id'] == $_GET['block'] ? 'selected' : '';`, and then add `$selected` to your block option: echo "<option $selected ...>...</option>`